This is one weird tool, Does anyone have any ideas what it is called?
This is one weird tool, Does anyone have any ideas what it is called?

Not my downvote, but a scale is much better shown with a ruler (with the units clear) than a random object not everyone will be familiar with - so not coins on an international forum. The lighter is an unfortunate choice as Bic make mini versions with very similar proportions to the big ones. Context would also help - found with garden tools? Workshop tools? In a kitchen?

It's a corn cutter similar to this one

https://carolinareadiness.com/products/corn-cutter-stainless-steel

That takes the fun out of eating corn...and of course then the age-old question of whether to eat in circles or typewriter style.
